# Disable unused variable warning just for underscore in g++/clang

Tags: g++, clang, compiler-warnings

Sometimes I use underscore to say do not care about this variable, e.g. for some return values of functions that return more than 1 value(e.g. map::insert) or iterating over a view when I do not need index, [e.g.](https://godbolt.org/z/YMT3EM8WG)

```
int main() {
    int cnt = 3;
    for(auto _ : std::views::iota(0,cnt)) {
        fmt::print("{}\n",100);
    }      
}
```

note: I know about `(void)`, `[[maybe_unused]]`, `pragma` to disable warning, I would like a way to disable the warning without source code changes, while it still being active for "normal" variable names.

I understand that g++/clang do not need to share my(or golang's ) convention of using underscore to mean unused variable, so I guess I am asking for a way to specify a list of "blank identifiers"

Comment: Strange that it seems there are no solutions to this yet. Sometimes there is no good way around it (i.e. in structured bindings). It'd also make sense to have warnings for when `_` IS used.